# Detect in a not-involved class if call was wrapped in a using of another

Tags: c#, design-patterns, singleton, using

*Firstly, sorry for the difficult question title, but I can't think of anything better.
If anybody knows a better description, I'd be happy to change the title! :)*

**Let's assume I have the following code with the two classes:**

```
using(new Wrapper())
{
    Inner.Do();
}

public class Wrapper : IDisposable
{
    public static Wrapper Instance { get; set; }
    public Wrapper()
    {
        Instance = this;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Instance = null;
    }
}
public static class Inner
{
    public static Do()
    {
        if (Wrapper.Instance == null)
        { /* no using */ }
        else
        { /* with using */ }
    }
}
```

Above code works as intended, and I am able to detect whether or not my code was wrapped up in a using statement or not.

Unfortunately, a static Instance variable is the best way I can think of to achieve the above, but it's certainly not best-case.
Assume that two Threads execute above code at the "same" time. One Thread would overwrite the Instance of the other, leading to unexcepted beaviour and race conditions.

**Question:**

Can anybody direct me to a solution where I am still able to do the above, but without the use of a static Instance variable?

Thanks in advance!

**ANSWER**

Since this is just a test for something new, I am now using the ThreadStaticAttribute.
But as Marc Gravell stated out, don't use this if there are async operations going on.

For usage see Kris Vandermotten's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would advise simply: not needing to do that. You are right in that there is no magic way to do that. The thread issue can be handled via `[ThreadStatic]`, but that won't work well when multiple threads are involved, for example `async`. If possible, I would say: find a different implementation strategy that doesn't require detecting unrelated `using` blocks. Equally, your code would struggle to detect the difference between `using` and simply:

```
new Wrapper(); // note this doesn't dispose cleanly
Inner.Do();
```

Another issue with some static instance is that you'd also need to consider multiple nested blocks; would need a `Stack<Wrapper>`, or you could cache the previous value to set it back to in the disposable object.

Comment: This is a great answer! I'll mark as correct it and write something in my original question. Be sure to read it!

Comment: I'll edited my question. Could you explain why this won't work well will multiple threads, since (as far as I undestood) the use-case for this attribute IS multiple threads?

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark the field backing the Instance property with a ThreadStatic attribute, like this:

```
[ThreadStatic]
private static Wrapper instance;

public static Wrapper Instance
{
    get { return instance; }
}
```

See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute.aspx

You may also have to deal with reentrance (i.e. nested usings).